# How to extract a video segment from a video using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am a newbie to FFMPEG, I am stuck at using FFMPEG to extract a segment of video. Since I am using the direct command line interface.
What would be the command line arguments if I am to extract say, video from frame 0 to frame 100000 or if I wanted to extract a video segment of 1 hour from a video that is 5 hours long?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah! Simple just add -t 01:00:00 to extract the 1 hour video.